# sqlalchemy disposing the connection pool right after creating a new connection

Tags: sqlalchemy, gunicorn, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a problem with sqlalchemy disposing the connection pool for some reason, I have no idea why.
This is the log I have:

```
2013-03-12 15:04:28 [19800] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
2013-03-12 15:04:28 [19800] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (19800)
2013-03-12 15:04:28 [19800] [INFO] Using worker: gevent
2013-03-12 15:04:28 [19881] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 19881
2013-03-12 15:04:29 [19881] [DEBUG] Created new connection <_mysql.connection open to 'XXX' at 8fb07a4>
2013-03-12 15:04:29 [19881] [INFO] SELECT DATABASE()
2013-03-12 15:04:29 [19881] [INFO] ()
2013-03-12 15:04:29 [19881] [INFO] Pool disposed. Pool size: 10  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -10 Current Checked out connections: 0
2013-03-12 15:04:29 [19881] [INFO] Pool recreating
```

This is with the latest sqlalchemy 0.8.0 and mysql 5.5 on solaris Oracle Solaris 10 9/10 s10x_u9wos_14a X86

**Edit:**

Here is a more detailed dump of what fails:

```
Created new connection <_mysql.connection open to 'XXXX' at 8bcb704>
SELECT DATABASE()
()
Pool disposed. Pool size: 10  Connections in pool: 0 Current Overflow: -10 Current Checked out connections: 0
Pool recreating
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/test/test_sqlalchemy.py", line 31, in <module>
    result = db.session.execute("select * from app_config")
  File "/test/bss/server/bss/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 149, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/test/bss/server/bss/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 931, in execute
    return self._connection_for_bind(bind, close_with_result=True).execute(
  File "/test/bss/server/bss/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 801, in _connection_for_bind
    return self.transaction._connection_for_bind(engine)
  File "/test/bss/server/bss/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 297, in _connection_for_bind
    conn = bind.contextual_connect()
  File "/test/bss/server/bss/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1669, in contextual_connect
    self.pool.connect(),
  File "/test/bss/server/bss/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 272, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy(self).checkout()
  File "/test/bss/server/bss/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 425, in __init__
    rec = self._connection_record = pool._do_get()
  File "/test/bss/server/bss/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 777, in _do_get
    con = self._create_connection()
  File "/test/bss/server/bss/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 225, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/test/bss/server/bss/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 322, in __init__
    exec_once(self.connection, self)
  File "/test/bss/server/bss/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event.py", line 392, in exec_once
    self(*args, **kw)
  File "/test/bss/server/bss/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event.py", line 409, in __call__
    fn(*args, **kw)
  File "/test/bss/server/bss/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 167, in first_connect
    dialect.initialize(c)
  File "/test/bss/server/bss/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/base.py", line 2055, in initialize
    default.DefaultDialect.initialize(self, connection)
  File "/test/bss/server/bss/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 171, in initialize
    self._get_default_schema_name(connection)
  File "/test/bss/server/bss/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/base.py", line 2022, in _get_default_schema_name
    return connection.execute('SELECT DATABASE()').scalar()
  File "/test/bss/server/bss/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 664, in execute
    params)
  File "/test/bss/server/bss/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 808, in _execute_text
    statement, parameters
  File "/test/bss/server/bss/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 878, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/test/bss/server/bss/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 871, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/test/bss/server/bss/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 320, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/test/bss/server/bss/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 201, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/test/bss/server/bss/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (InterfaceError) (0, '') 'SELECT DATABASE()' ()
```

Any ideas what is the problem?

Comment: Can you show us some code of how you are creating your engine,  session etc. and can you track where it disposes your pool?

Comment: it looks like your MySQL-python adapter is malfunctioning, like it's built incorrectly, or something is very wrong with your database.  it establishes a connection, but then fails on the first SQL emitted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what causes this problem but with oursql instead of mysql-python everything works just fine.